# How to keep image in it's original form when dark mode enabled

Tags: android, android-theme, android-10.0

I just created a media application for android. When user play a song it shows title and image in a notification. I have a problem when user play a song in android built in dark theme (android 10) then notification image got inverted. How can I get rid of this, I search on internet and got nothing about this.

Comment: How did you create the notification? Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: And you can create a custom notification style: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification

Comment: Did you find any solution?